# Apple developer account - remove team ID from agent

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, fastlane, apple-developer, fastlane-match

I was the team agent of an enterprise account but after joining a new team in Fastlane match I get the option to choose between the team I was an agent of and new invited team.

```
[14:03:47]: Fetching certificates and profiles...
Multiple teams found on the Developer Portal, please enter the number of the team you want to use: 
1) xxxxx "some.org" (Company/Organization)
2) yyyyy "some.org" (In-House)
```

How do I remove the previous agent account yyyyy so this option isn't showing up.

when trying to exit in membership option in developer.apple.com I can't exit as an Agent but have the option to "Transfer Team Agent Role"[image]. I don't want to transfer just delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need somebody to remove you from one of those accounts or your could specify an environment variable or command line arguments so that you aren't prompted. It looks like you are using `match` here so...

Using CLI: `match --team_id xxx` or `match --team_name "some.org"`

Using environment variable: `FASTLANE_TEAM_ID=xxx match` or you can set this environment variable in your system

If you are using a Fastfile and calling the `match` action, you could do `match(team_id: "xxx")` or `match(team_name: "some.org")`

You can view docs by either executing `fastlane match --help`, executing `fastlane action match`, or by viewing the docs here - https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/match/#match

Comment: thanks, I added the team id parameter in match to avoid the prompt.